# How to structure components in FP?

Tags: functional-programming

In OOP, I was structuring my code by composition, having grapes  of components, and I was some kind of happy with it...Everything were tidy in boxes :-) What is considered good practices in pure FP ?

I guess just a Haskell Module that exposes the component publicly useful ? Should I play with data types ?

e.g : In Domain Driven Design : Services -> Repositories

- ServiceA (serviceX, serviceY, repo1,repo2,repo3)
- ServiceB (serviceA, serviceC, serviceZ, repo1,repo2,repo3)
- ServiceC (serviceA, serviceB)

Things that change in pure FP is that I don't need an instantiation of all these object, I have just a grape of functions now... The mindset is quite different... 
In my current code all the dependencies are hidden like if I was using "static function everywhere in my code" which is terribly bad for testing in OOP...

How should I think in pure FP ?

Comment: I think it's not a bad question, but you should at least narrow it down to some concrete example in OO. Even so I'm not sure it would qualify as an on-topic SO question.

Comment: yeah I know, I'm bending the use of stackoverflow a bit :-)  I'm trying to make it more concrete :-)

Comment: Another common approach in the world of FP is to keep the most generic functions away from the partial applications and other kind of games you can possibly play with functions. However, it does not cover your question entirely.

Comment: Yeah. — I don't know if your “concrete example” is clear to people more acquainted with OO than me, but even so it could use some elaboration. At least I haven't a clue what these “services” are supposed to mean, why not add some actual code?

Comment: @leftaroundabout , you may like what I've found :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander Granin started to write a book about "Functional design and Architecture", he didn't finish that book unfortunately but he did a part of it which is absolutely worth reading : [Sources](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1Rdr1fbS6M9SjlKUk1zMVNjOVU)

You'll find all the details [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6ck72h/functional_design_and_architecture/) as well :

> - Architecture modelling, requirements analysis, subsystems design from    FP point of view;
> - Embedded and external DSLs in domain modelling;
> - Monads as subsystems with effects;
> - Free monads as functional interfaces;
> - Other types of functional interfaces;
> - Inversion of Control in FP (using Free monadic eDSLs);
> - STM, IO Ref, MVars as concurrent application state;
> - Lenses;
> - State, Reader, Writer, RWS, ST monads in subsystems design;
> - GUI and FP;
> - Applicability of mainstream techniques and approaches such as    UML,SOLID, GRASP;
> - Interaction with impure subsystems.

I hope somebody will pay him time to finish it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach is not that different.
Briefly:

1. Always go from the most generic to the most specific abstractions. It does apply to the OOP as well, however FP tends to be more explicit on that. In particular, it means that you keep generic not-yet-partially-applied functions far away from modules consuming those.
2. Composition. It is good to keep your "primitive" functions away from the compositions, especially long ones. You might treat this as a subitem of the #1, though I would classify this as self-important thing. (Warning! Some languages like F# force newcommers to proceed on something like `(|>)` operators to compose functions. That's not your way: do not evaluate them, otherwise you can't achieve what I am saying here about: make sure your composition indeed produces new function and you decide when to run it).
3. Never ever ever mix IO or mutable codebase (IO monad in case of Haskell) with pure codebase.
4. Define type synonymous and new types, when appropriate. Configure your (Haskell) modules to export only those bits, you'd like to be available for consumers rather then entire module (except the case when such a module is rather simple, of course).